# How to insert multiline data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, unix

**I have a command in my script that goes like this**

```
MESSAGE=`grep -Po 'MSG.\K[\w\s,.'\'',.:]*' < $FILENAME`
```

**Now when this command is run I have an output which look like this**

```
Kohl's EDI will be down for scheduled maintenance starting at 12:30 am until
approximately 4:00 am central time on Wednesday June 22nd. Kohl's will not be
able to send or receive EDI or AS2 transmissions during this time. If your
company's AS2 software has an automated process to resend a file after a
failure, Kohl's encourages your company to enable the resend process. This     is
also a reminder for AS2 trading partners that Kohl's AS2 certificate will be
changing at 11:00 am central time on Tuesday June 21st.
```

**Now after grepping the whole thing out I would pass the result of the command to a variable that will be used so that I can store the result to a mysql database**

The question is How will I do it?

Comment: `$LINE` contains the name of a file, or the data in which you want to grep?

Comment: yes @anishsane it contains the name of the file I want to grep

Comment: Then your mechanism is correct. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @anishsane I have the problem in inserting it already in the database. I think it does not insert to the database because what I store on the variable is a multipile lines. How do I store the result in one variable so that I can insert it to the database

Comment: Ok, then your question is _"how to insert multiline data in mysql database"_ , not _"How do I store the grepped result to variable if the result has multiple lines?"_; because you are doing the latter correctly.

Comment: OK sorry for that .. so do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks for the correction by the way.

Comment: Oh, never mind... But no, I have not used mysql much, cannot answer this...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have connection to mysql from the server and then you can pass MEASSGE variable in insert statement as `\"$MESSAGE\"` - `\` is because of wrapping message in double quotes for valid insert statement.

**Test:** I did not have enough bigger column to store entire message as yours so I trimmed it little to fit in the column:

```
> MESSAGE="Kohl's EDI will be down for scheduled maintenance starting at 12:30 am until
approximately 4:00 am central time on Wednesday June 22nd. Kohl's will not be
able to send or receive EDI or AS2 transmissions during this time. If your
company's AS2 software has an automated process to resend a file after a
"
> sql "insert into at_test_run (run_id,run_error) values ('10000111',\"$MESSAGE\");"
> sql "select run_id,run_error from at_test_run where run_id='10000111'"
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| run_id   | run_error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10000111 | Kohl's EDI will be down for scheduled maintenance starting at 12:30 am until
approximately 4:00 am central time on Wednesday June 22nd. Kohl's will not be
able to send or receive EDI or AS2 transmissions during this time. If your
company's AS2 software has an automated process to resend a file after a
 |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```